# StatusCode.UNAUTHENTICATED Google assistant Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I am trying to run google assistant on my windows computer and have been following this guide: [XDA developers guide](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-get-google-assistant-on-your-windows-mac-or-linux-machine/)

When I run:

```
python -m googlesamples.assistant.grpc.pushtotalk
```

and then hit enter so send a command I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\googlesamples\assistant\grpc\pushtotalk.py", line 328, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\googlesamples\assistant\grpc\pushtotalk.py", line 317, in main
    continue_conversation = assistant.converse()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 87, in wrapped_f
    return r.call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 235, in call
    do = self.iter(result=result, exc_info=exc_info)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 194, in iter
    return fut.result()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 238, in call
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\googlesamples\assistant\grpc\pushtotalk.py", line 110, in converse
    self.deadline):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 349, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 343, in _next
    raise self
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNAUTHENTICATED, Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com
/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.)>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to wait until they fix that, the bug is on Google's side. Here is the issue they opened at github:

https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/138